# Trying to send specific columns of a dataframe to a new csv file, always returning empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

This is the my piece of code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('E:/cnpj/socios.csv', quotechar='"', sep=',', usecols=["cnpj", "nome_socio"], warn_bad_lines=True, error_bad_lines=False, low_memory=False, nrows=100000)
#df.set_index(['cnpj'], inplace=True)
print (df.head)
result = df[df['cnpj'].isin(["191"])]
print(result)
```

This is what it returns:

```
<bound method NDFrame.head of          cnpj                    nome_socio
0         191      MARCIO HAMILTON FERREIRA
1         191     NILSON MARTINIANO MOREIRA
2         191         WALTER MALIENI JUNIOR
3         191   CARLOS ALBERTO ARAUJO NETTO
4         191      ANTONIO MAURICIO MAURANO
...       ...                           ...
99995  172561   CARLOS ALBERTO ARAUJO NETTO
99996  172561      ANTONIO MAURICIO MAURANO
99997  172561  MARCELO AUGUSTO DUTRA LABUTO
99998  172561           ROGERIO MAGNO PANCA
99999  172561               TARCISIO HUBNER

[100000 rows x 2 columns]>
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [cnpj, nome_socio]
Index: []
```

The thing is: I want to get the column 'cnpj', compare it to a value (in this case, "191") and when it finds a row where the column has this value, send it to the dataframe "result", and them write it into a csv file.

But, as you can see, the pd dataframe reads the file correctly, but the code I'm using to do the comparison and write the "result" dataframe always returns an empty dataframe.

Any insights?

ps: A sample of the file goes like this:

"cnpj","nome_socio"

"191","MARCIO HAMILTON FERREIRA"

"191","NILSON MARTINIANO MOREIRA"

"191","WALTER MALIENI JUNIOR"

"191","CARLOS ALBERTO ARAUJO NETTO"

"191","ANTONIO MAURICIO MAURANO"

"172561","CARLOS ALBERTO ARAUJO NETTO"

"172561","ANTONIO MAURICIO MAURANO"

"172561","MARCELO AUGUSTO DUTRA LABUTO"

"172561","ROGERIO MAGNO PANCA"

"172561","TARCISIO HUBNER"

Comment: I used a toy example on my side and couldn't reproduce what you're receiving. Could you show all the code that led to the output above ?

Comment: That's the whole code for this problem. The .csv file got " " as delimiters, though. Including in the header.

Comment: The sample for the header in the file would go like this:

"cnpj","nome_socio"
"191","MARCIO HAMILTON FERREIRA"
"191","NILSON MARTINIANO MOREIRA"
"191","WALTER MALIENI JUNIOR"
"191","CARLOS ALBERTO ARAUJO NETTO"
"191","ANTONIO MAURICIO MAURANO"
"172561","CARLOS ALBERTO ARAUJO NETTO"
"172561","ANTONIO MAURICIO MAURANO"
"172561","MARCELO AUGUSTO DUTRA LABUTO"
"172561","ROGERIO MAGNO PANCA"
"172561","TARCISIO HUBNER"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend, you are comparing "191" as String, and I think your data is as Integer. Try change you code like this:

```
result = df[df['cnpj'].isin([191])]
```

Another suggestion. If you are not comparing a list of possible values, try something like this:

```
result = df.loc[df['cnpj'] = 191]
```

I would also advise you to clean your code before filtering. Remove duplicates, etc.

To save as CSV, pandas has the DataFrame.to_csv function.

Regards!

Comment: You are right! Changing to integer did the trick. I never thought it would go like this, since in the .csv they are all strings, but surely pandas did the conversion.